# Bootstrap 3, data-show not working

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I'm using the modal-plugin supported by Bootstrap 3 (http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals) with the following mark-up:

```
<div class=​"modal fade" id=​"login_modal" tabindex=​"-1" role=​"dialog" aria-labelledby=​"myModalLabel" aria-hidden=​"true" data-show=​"true">​…​</div>​
```

According to the documentation this should work with the ***data-show*** attribute.. Unfortunately the modal won't show automatically when the page finished loading. I don't see anything wrong here so I hope one of you guys could spot the problem for me please.

P.S.:
I also found an similar existent but already closed issue they had with modals which seem to have been rewritten in v3 so I don't think it's up-to-date (https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/5891).

***EDIT***
What I forgot to mention is that I included bootstrap of course. With a button to open and close it, it works just fine. :) It's really just the data-show attribute not doing what it's supposed to

Comment: Try to use jQuery option then? `$('#myModal').modal('show');` Though if your question is more into curiosity as to why `data-show` doesn't work, I couldn't get it to work myself either, out of the box.

Comment: Well looks like I gotta create an issue on github then...and/or commit a patch =)

Comment: I am having the same problem. Did you end up creating an issue for this on their github page?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's actually not a bug because the [documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals) says:

> Shows the modal when initialized.

Therefore you need to initialize your Modal "manually" by JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $( function(){
        $('#myModal').modal();
    } )
</script>
```

Comment: The documentation might be misleading one to think the data-show attribute initialises a modal on page load when it doesn't. Actually, the default value for this options is already set to "true".

Answer (score 4):

If `data-show="true"`, then when you call `$('.modal').modal()`, the modal shows up. But if `data-show="false"`, `$('.modal').modal()` doesn't work, you need to call `$('.modal').modal('show')` instead.

Comment: That should be the Answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('*[data-show]').modal('show');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit old but I've had the same problem right now. I'm helping me out with an additional style class (show) and some general JavaScript:

```
<div class="modal fade show" id="modalEdit" role="dialog" ... >
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            ...
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.modal.show').modal('show');
});
```

This allows me to simply add the style class and toggle the behaviour as needed.

Answer (score -2):

I don't think such attribute exists in Bootstrap. I agree it would be convenient (and certainly easy to implement since the js version is already there), but as far as I've read, the documentation only mentions `data-toggle` attributes.

Did you report an issue?

Comment: This is documented under http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-usage - under "Options: show"

Comment: That's right. The interesting thing though, is that the default option to `data-show` is `true`, which means it should not be necessary to write it. On the other hand, preloading a page with a modal should always trigger its modals then, which is certainly not the behaviour I've experimented so far.

Comment: Yes, I agree it does not appear to be working as documented which is a bit frustrating. I've had to resort to selecting all the modals I want to show on start via jquery and launching them via JS. I found using data-show not only didn't work, it caused the modals to malfunction when launched via .modal('show')

Comment: Yeah, there are quite some features that don't seem to be executed onload and it's a pity we need to add our own script to run it. Though it *could* be a bootstrap for obscur reason we don't know. Another example is checked checkboxes in `data-toggle"buttons"` which are not automatically set to active...